# Why back emf in an inductor reduces gradually?

Tags: electromagnetic-induction, inductance

In an inductor if there is current supply, flux associated with it increases generating emf opposing voltage supply. Now flux remains constant for a smallest time interval, so back emf reduces, which increases current through inductor , increasing magnetic field strength.  So flux again increases, provoking back emf. This makes me think that back emf should remain constant,  not decrease.
Why back emf reduces gradually?

Answer (score 1):

If an ideal voltage source is connected to an ideal inductor, the current continues to increase at a rate that keeps the back emf equal to the voltage.  If there is any resistance in the circuit, then as the current increases, the voltage across the resistance increases, and the voltage (and back emf) on the inductor decreases.